# sql: mapping two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Customer daily payment transaction data for years in time order:
The first column is customerID, second column is transactionID, which is the primary key.  Third to fifth columns are TransactionDate, TransactionType and TransactionAmount. TransactionType could be either normal transaction ("ACH") with positive TransactionAmount or decline record ("ACH rejections") of a previous transaction with negative TransactionAmount. A Rejection usually happen within 3 business days. I'd like to map a rejection record back to its initial transaction by using CustomID and CustomAmount matching.

How to do this in SQL for a big dataset?

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: This a table on a MS SQL Server,  softdevlife has provided a perfect data sample. Desired output is an extra column, which corresponds to the mapped ACH transaction ID for a ACH rejection, and the ACH rejection transaction ID for a ACH if it is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is the metadata and some examples that fit your business case.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_payment_transaction (
  customerID        bigint NOT NULL, 
  transactionID     bigint PRIMARY KEY, 
  TransactionDate   timestamp NOT NULL, 
  TransactionType   varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
  TransactionAmount decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customer_payment_transaction 
VALUES 
(1,1, '2017-12-10 09:34:54', 'ACH'            ,   24.88),
(1,2, '2017-12-11 09:34:54', 'ACH'            ,   34.88),
(1,3, '2017-12-12 09:34:54', 'ACH rejections' ,  -34.88),
(2,4, '2017-12-13 09:34:54', 'ACH'            ,   54.88),
(2,5, '2017-12-14 09:34:54', 'ACH'            ,   94.88),
(2,6, '2017-12-15 09:34:54', 'ACH'            ,  104.88),
(2,7, '2017-12-16 09:34:54', 'ACH rejections' ,  -94.88),
(2,8, '2017-12-17 09:34:54', 'ACH rejections' , -104.88),
(1,9, '2017-12-17 10:34:54', 'ACH'            ,   24.88),
(1,10,'2017-12-18 09:34:54', 'ACH rejections' ,  -24.88);
```

Then solution would be as follows

```
SELECT
      inbound.customerID, 
      inbound.TransactionAmount     AS transaction_amount,
      MIN(inbound.TransactionDate)  AS purchase_date,
      MIN(outbound.TransactionDate) AS reject_date

   FROM       customer_payment_transaction inbound

   INNER JOIN customer_payment_transaction outbound
   ON  outbound.customerID              = inbound.customerID
   AND ABS(outbound.TransactionAmount)  = inbound.TransactionAmount
   AND outbound.TransactionDate         < DATE_ADD(inbound.TransactionDate, INTERVAL 72 HOUR)
   AND outbound.TransactionType         = 'ACH rejections'

   WHERE inbound.TransactionType = 'ACH'

   GROUP BY inbound.customerID,  inbound.TransactionAmount
```

Try it on http://sqlfiddle.com/

This will not be accurate if there are two outbound **OR** two inbound with same `CustomerID, TransactionAmount` within 72 hours. In those use cases, you will need other identifier columns that you will either need to find or create.

Comment: Thank you, softdevlife! The data is exactly the same as your example. And indeed it often happens that several ACH rejections with exactly the same custom ID and amount show up in the same day. As there is no other indicator that could be used to link a ACH rejection with the actual payment, my best hope is to achieve a one-to-one mapping, say, if a rejection is attached with a payment date, it will not be used again. Do you think it is possible? The ACH itself could be assumed as at most once per day for the same custom ID with the same amount.

Comment: Although storing the timestamp for an actual payment within a rejection transaction is almost reliable (outbound.PaymentTransactionDate = inbound.TransactionDate), storing the payment ID of the actual payment within a rejection transaction guarantees a one-to-one mapping and is more efficient (outbound.payment_transactionID = inbound.transactionID). Either columns which you will need to group by need to be add it in the system and cannot be fabricated with suggested queries. Which transaction gets rejected if said customer buys same item within 72 hours & rejects only one out of two items?

Comment: Moving forward, without a system in place storing the actual values, you will be making speculations with a level of bias. Even then, in my opinion, the solution is out of T-SQL scope. You will need to write some code that has a set of payments that checks whether there is a valid rejection in the set of rejections (within 72 hours, same customer id and transaction amount). If valid, you reference the transaction ID of said rejection in your set of payments and remove that rejection on your rejection set. You then move on to your next payment.

Comment: You discussed the dataset is big, but you only need to do this only once and afterward only for the last 3 days on a daily basis. If the dataset is too big, you can split it into specific date ranges (i.e. Reference the first 30 days of payments by extracting the first 33 days of transactions).